# How to say "very impressive"?

Tags: translation

How to translate "very impressive" into German?

Comment: If you provide an example or context, the answers will target your needs better.

Comment: Indeed, yes, you should provide context. With a description of the situation where you would like to use a German way of saying "very impressive", this would even have a chance to become a legitimate question here in this forum, because for answering it you cannot simply refer to a dictionary, but rather need native speakers' experience. So, your context?

Answer (score 4):

The most versatile translation would be

> sehr beeindruckend

Answer (score 2):

```
 sehr eindrucksvoll
```

Is also a good possibility.